# Windows 2008 black screen and mouse pointer

Tags: windows-server-2008

After adding a local user admin to permissions for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT in registry editor,
and computer restart, system cannot boot When the system loads,after the Windows logo and load screen (before login screen) there is a black screen with only the mouse showing
and I cannot even boot into Safe Mode. I tried to repair windows or edit registry with HIREN'S Boot CD but No results were not.

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question.

Comment: @MDMarra My windows does not load up and I just see black screen, I need help to find and fix issue

Answer (score 1):

Restore from your last good backup.

Comment: +1 The registry is hosed... time to learn from your mistakes and restore from backup.